# How can I use each loop variable (item) outside of loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a switch for declaring variables inside each loop, like this

```
switch (label) {
case "Users":
  content = item.username+ ' ' + item.firstname + ' '
    + item.lastname + '('+ item.organization + ')';
  break;
default:
}

$.each(result, function (i, item) {
  html += "<option value ='" + item.id + "'>" + content + "</option>";
});
```

But since item variable hasn't defined yet I will get an ReferenceError.

**Moving switch inside loop will make It really slow.**

Is this even possible to declare loop variables outside of scope?

```
function selectorAddEdit(label, tag, result, labelconf) {
  var idtag = tag+"s";
  var none = "<option value='None'>None</option>";
  var labelHead = (labelconf=="head") ? "<div class='selectTitles'><label>"+label+"</label></div>" : "";

  switch (label) {
  case "Users":
    var content = item.username + ' ' + item.firstname + ' ' + item.lastname + '('+ item.organization + ')';
    break;
  default:
  }

  var html = labelHead + "<select name='" + tag + "' class='" + tag + "'>";
  $.each(result, function (i, item) {
    html += "<option value ='" + item.id + "'>" + content + "</option>";
  });

  html += "</select></div>";

  $("." + idtag).html(html);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the `content` as a global  variable

```
 var content="";    
switch (label) {
        case "Users":
        content = item.username+ ' ' + item.firstname + ' ' + item.lastname + '('+ item.organization + ')';
          break;
        default:

      }

      $.each(result, function (i, item) {
        html += "<option value ='"+item.id+"'>"+content+"</option>";
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is assuming that `item` is distinct/unique and therefore you want the `switch` statement to be re-evaluated at each iteration of loop. What you can do is to use a method/function that returns the value, after evaluating a given condition:

```
var getOptionContent = function(item) {
    switch (label) {
        case "Users":
            return item.username + ' ' + item.firstname + ' ' + item.lastname + '(' + item.organization + ')';
        default:
            return '';
    }
}

var html = labelHead + "<select name='" + tag + "' class='" + tag + "'>";
$.each(result, function(i, item) {
    html += "<option value ='" + item.id + "'>" + getOptionContent(item) + "</option>";
});
```